# Solr: Text_en vs string for display& index field

Tags: search, indexing, solr, storage

I am trying to decide if I should use text_en or string as my fieldtype. The field is firstname and has to be both indexed and stored for display. I am displaying the contents on the webpage by reading the data from solr index.

The text_en has just an index analyzer which would tokenize the contents of the firstname column. And there is no transformation when it stores the data.
On the other hand string fields dont undergo any transformations either while storing or indexing the data.

Solr should return results when someone searches for John or john.

Can someone comment why using one over another might be beneficial.
Thanks

Comment: In your case, I would go with a custom type `TextField` with a `LowerCaseTokenizer` (both index and query time).

Answer (score 2):

As @shitsu commented - you really don't have a choice. You want to be able to lowercase the content, and still display the original form - so a TextField is the way to go. If you want to split tokens (so that "Paul John" can be searched by just entering "Paul" or "john", `text_en` will be able to do that. You can adjust this by defining your own field type with a Tokenizer suited for your needs.

If you just want to give exact hits, but regardless of case, having a `KeywordTokenizer` with a `LowercaseFilter` is probably what you're looking for. This will lowercase all the text, but still index it as a single token (so it has to match completely).